# Does Spring (3) have any built in support for pagination?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, pagination

I have a model I need to paginate (Book listings - [as explained in a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710771/deciding-on-a-strategy-for-paginating-book-listings-without-sql).).

This seems like a common enough feature that I would expect some pre-built solutions for it without having to build a custom solution.

Does Spring (3) have support for pagination?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to implement pagination in Spring MVC 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245035/how-to-implement-pagination-in-spring-mvc-3)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some helper classes included. For instance there's a class called org.springframework.beans.support.PagedListHolder. There are a number of solutions to pagination depending on what trade-offs you're willing to make, so there is no one single accepted way to do it. [This article](http://www.developer.com/java/web/article.php/3830886/A-Pagination-Technique-Using-Spring.htm) has a good overview.

Answer (score 1):

Spring Data has support for web pagination, as described here:

http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/reference/html/repositories.html#web-pagination